# What's wrong with my use of reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays

`d_loc` is a array of object with a property called `'Common Name'`. I'm trying to return a array of all unique 'Common Name'.
This is not working, could you help me ?

```
d_loc.reduce( (acc, cur) => ( acc.indexOf(cur['Common Name'])<0 ? acc.push(cur['Common Name']) ) , [] )
```

I've added a sample data.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```js
d_loc = [{
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "Wandering Whistling-Duck",
  "Scientific Name": "Dendrocygna arcuata",
  "Taxonomic Order": "218",
  "Count": "2",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "Wandering Whistling-Duck",
  "Scientific Name": "Dendrocygna arcuata",
  "Taxonomic Order": "218",
  "Count": "6",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "Green Pygmy-Goose",
  "Scientific Name": "Nettapus pulchellus",
  "Taxonomic Order": "351",
  "Count": "20",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "Green Pygmy-Goose",
  "Scientific Name": "Nettapus pulchellus",
  "Taxonomic Order": "351",
  "Count": "30",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "Brown Goshawk",
  "Scientific Name": "Accipiter fasciatus",
  "Taxonomic Order": "2730",
  "Count": "1",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "Black Kite",
  "Scientific Name": "Milvus migrans",
  "Taxonomic Order": "2855",
  "Count": "10",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "Black Kite",
  "Scientific Name": "Milvus migrans",
  "Taxonomic Order": "2855",
  "Count": "200",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "Whistling Kite",
  "Scientific Name": "Haliastur sphenurus",
  "Taxonomic Order": "2870",
  "Count": "3",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "Blue-winged Kookaburra",
  "Scientific Name": "Dacelo leachii",
  "Taxonomic Order": "9672",
  "Count": "1",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "kingfisher sp.",
  "Scientific Name": "Alcedinidae sp.",
  "Taxonomic Order": "9949",
  "Count": "1",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "Sacred?",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "Rainbow Bee-eater",
  "Scientific Name": "Merops ornatus",
  "Taxonomic Order": "10007",
  "Count": "5",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "Rainbow Bee-eater",
  "Scientific Name": "Merops ornatus",
  "Taxonomic Order": "10007",
  "Count": "5",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "Red-winged Parrot",
  "Scientific Name": "Aprosmictus erythropterus",
  "Taxonomic Order": "11587.333",
  "Count": "1",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "Rainbow Lorikeet",
  "Scientific Name": "Trichoglossus haematodus",
  "Taxonomic Order": "11587.776295",
  "Count": "2",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "White-gaped Honeyeater",
  "Scientific Name": "Stomiopera unicolor",
  "Taxonomic Order": "15687",
  "Count": "5",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "White-gaped Honeyeater",
  "Scientific Name": "Stomiopera unicolor",
  "Taxonomic Order": "15687",
  "Count": "5",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "Yellow-tinted Honeyeater",
  "Scientific Name": "Ptilotula flavescens",
  "Taxonomic Order": "15763",
  "Count": "3",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "Brown Honeyeater",
  "Scientific Name": "Lichmera indistincta",
  "Taxonomic Order": "15895",
  "Count": "10",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "Brown Honeyeater",
  "Scientific Name": "Lichmera indistincta",
  "Taxonomic Order": "15895",
  "Count": "10",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "Blue-faced Honeyeater",
  "Scientific Name": "Entomyzon cyanotis",
  "Taxonomic Order": "15925",
  "Count": "2",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "White-breasted Woodswallow",
  "Scientific Name": "Artamus leucorynchus",
  "Taxonomic Order": "16887",
  "Count": "2",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "To double-check",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "Masked Woodswallow",
  "Scientific Name": "Artamus personatus",
  "Taxonomic Order": "16898",
  "Count": "5",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "Olive-backed Oriole",
  "Scientific Name": "Oriolus sagittatus",
  "Taxonomic Order": "17987",
  "Count": "1",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "worn feature? wired color...",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "Magpie-lark",
  "Scientific Name": "Grallina cyanoleuca",
  "Taxonomic Order": "18638",
  "Count": "5",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "Magpie-lark",
  "Scientific Name": "Grallina cyanoleuca",
  "Taxonomic Order": "18638",
  "Count": "10",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "Australian Reed Warbler",
  "Scientific Name": "Acrocephalus australis",
  "Taxonomic Order": "22269",
  "Count": "5",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "Australian Reed Warbler",
  "Scientific Name": "Acrocephalus australis",
  "Taxonomic Order": "22269",
  "Count": "5",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "Golden-headed Cisticola",
  "Scientific Name": "Cisticola exilis",
  "Taxonomic Order": "22890",
  "Count": "3",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "Golden-headed Cisticola",
  "Scientific Name": "Cisticola exilis",
  "Taxonomic Order": "22890",
  "Count": "2",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "Mistletoebird",
  "Scientific Name": "Dicaeum hirundinaceum",
  "Taxonomic Order": "26942",
  "Count": "1",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}]

d_loc.reduce( (acc, cur) => ( acc.indexOf(cur['Common Name'])<0 ? acc.push(cur['Common Name']) ) , [] )
```

Comment: Syntax Error: Incomplete ternary.

Comment: you need an 'else' part

Comment: Also keep in mind that it is generally adviced not to use ternary expression to control execution flow.

Comment: Since I was alreadty writing my answer when this was closed, I'll at least put it as comment, copied in gist: https://gist.github.com/Darker/3acd957d0323ad72870e55700e61388c

Comment: Thanks @TomášZato for your answer. reduce seems faster than the iteration (see answer below). Would you still not recommend it?

Comment: All the fancy `Array.prototype.hwatever` are just hidden `for` loops and they are not significantly faster. Why would you think reduce is faster?

Comment: @Tushar that is not the only issue with OP's code though.

Comment: @TomášZato, here the code I've used... https://jsfiddle.net/um91w84k/. Really not an expert... so forgive me if I'm completely mistaken...

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Else missing and `concat` instead of `push` !
Thanks,

```
d_loc.reduce( (acc, cur) =>  acc.indexOf(cur['Common Name'])<0 ? acc.concat(cur['Common Name']) : acc , [] )
```

```js
d_loc = [{
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "Wandering Whistling-Duck",
  "Scientific Name": "Dendrocygna arcuata",
  "Taxonomic Order": "218",
  "Count": "2",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "Wandering Whistling-Duck",
  "Scientific Name": "Dendrocygna arcuata",
  "Taxonomic Order": "218",
  "Count": "6",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "Green Pygmy-Goose",
  "Scientific Name": "Nettapus pulchellus",
  "Taxonomic Order": "351",
  "Count": "20",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "Green Pygmy-Goose",
  "Scientific Name": "Nettapus pulchellus",
  "Taxonomic Order": "351",
  "Count": "30",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "Brown Goshawk",
  "Scientific Name": "Accipiter fasciatus",
  "Taxonomic Order": "2730",
  "Count": "1",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "Black Kite",
  "Scientific Name": "Milvus migrans",
  "Taxonomic Order": "2855",
  "Count": "10",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "Black Kite",
  "Scientific Name": "Milvus migrans",
  "Taxonomic Order": "2855",
  "Count": "200",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "Whistling Kite",
  "Scientific Name": "Haliastur sphenurus",
  "Taxonomic Order": "2870",
  "Count": "3",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "Blue-winged Kookaburra",
  "Scientific Name": "Dacelo leachii",
  "Taxonomic Order": "9672",
  "Count": "1",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "kingfisher sp.",
  "Scientific Name": "Alcedinidae sp.",
  "Taxonomic Order": "9949",
  "Count": "1",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "Sacred?",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "Rainbow Bee-eater",
  "Scientific Name": "Merops ornatus",
  "Taxonomic Order": "10007",
  "Count": "5",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "Rainbow Bee-eater",
  "Scientific Name": "Merops ornatus",
  "Taxonomic Order": "10007",
  "Count": "5",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "Red-winged Parrot",
  "Scientific Name": "Aprosmictus erythropterus",
  "Taxonomic Order": "11587.333",
  "Count": "1",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "Rainbow Lorikeet",
  "Scientific Name": "Trichoglossus haematodus",
  "Taxonomic Order": "11587.776295",
  "Count": "2",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "White-gaped Honeyeater",
  "Scientific Name": "Stomiopera unicolor",
  "Taxonomic Order": "15687",
  "Count": "5",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "White-gaped Honeyeater",
  "Scientific Name": "Stomiopera unicolor",
  "Taxonomic Order": "15687",
  "Count": "5",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "Yellow-tinted Honeyeater",
  "Scientific Name": "Ptilotula flavescens",
  "Taxonomic Order": "15763",
  "Count": "3",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "Brown Honeyeater",
  "Scientific Name": "Lichmera indistincta",
  "Taxonomic Order": "15895",
  "Count": "10",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "Brown Honeyeater",
  "Scientific Name": "Lichmera indistincta",
  "Taxonomic Order": "15895",
  "Count": "10",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "Blue-faced Honeyeater",
  "Scientific Name": "Entomyzon cyanotis",
  "Taxonomic Order": "15925",
  "Count": "2",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "White-breasted Woodswallow",
  "Scientific Name": "Artamus leucorynchus",
  "Taxonomic Order": "16887",
  "Count": "2",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "To double-check",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "Masked Woodswallow",
  "Scientific Name": "Artamus personatus",
  "Taxonomic Order": "16898",
  "Count": "5",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "Olive-backed Oriole",
  "Scientific Name": "Oriolus sagittatus",
  "Taxonomic Order": "17987",
  "Count": "1",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "worn feature? wired color...",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "Magpie-lark",
  "Scientific Name": "Grallina cyanoleuca",
  "Taxonomic Order": "18638",
  "Count": "5",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "Magpie-lark",
  "Scientific Name": "Grallina cyanoleuca",
  "Taxonomic Order": "18638",
  "Count": "10",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "Australian Reed Warbler",
  "Scientific Name": "Acrocephalus australis",
  "Taxonomic Order": "22269",
  "Count": "5",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "Australian Reed Warbler",
  "Scientific Name": "Acrocephalus australis",
  "Taxonomic Order": "22269",
  "Count": "5",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38214536",
  "Common Name": "Golden-headed Cisticola",
  "Scientific Name": "Cisticola exilis",
  "Taxonomic Order": "22890",
  "Count": "3",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-19-2017",
  "Time": "01:49 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "73",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "4",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "We were told to go there for Baillon's Crake and White-browed"
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "Golden-headed Cisticola",
  "Scientific Name": "Cisticola exilis",
  "Taxonomic Order": "22890",
  "Count": "2",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}, {
  "Submission ID": "S38326806",
  "Common Name": "Mistletoebird",
  "Scientific Name": "Dicaeum hirundinaceum",
  "Taxonomic Order": "26942",
  "Count": "1",
  "State/Province": "AU-WA",
  "County": "Wyndham-East Kimberley",
  "Location": "Celebrity Tree Park",
  "Latitude": "-15.7857217",
  "Longitude": "128.737742",
  "Date": "07-25-2017",
  "Time": "12:17 PM",
  "Protocol": "eBird - Stationary Count",
  "Duration (Min)": "89",
  "All Obs Reported": "1",
  "Distance Traveled (km)": "",
  "Area Covered (ha)": "",
  "Number of Observers": "2",
  "Breeding Code": "",
  "Species Comments": "",
  "Checklist Comments": "Trying to find the other crake."
}]

console.time("solution1");
sol1 = d_loc.reduce( (acc, cur) =>  acc.indexOf(cur['Common Name'])<0 ? acc.concat(cur['Common Name']) : acc , [] )
console.timeEnd("solution1");

console.time("solution2");
sol2 = [];
result = d_loc.forEach( (userInfo) => { 
 name = userInfo['Common Name'];
 if(sol2.indexOf(name)<0)
  sol2.push(name) 
 } ,
[] )

console.timeEnd("solution2");

console.log(sol1)
console.log(sol2)
```

Comment: You should not answer a typographical mistake for start. Second, answering your own question is a way to show some research

Comment: @Rajesh, sorry for my mistake. Why can I not answer a typo? yes, I could have wait before posting the question. I actually ask another person after who showed my mistake. So, lesson to learn, this is not a place to ask a question about a mistake, right?

Comment: Lesson to learn is, you should first check your console for errors. If not, look for documentation. If you are not satisfied, post a question and we will help as we did here. There is nothing wrong with a typo mistake. Whats wrong is you are answering it. Its very unlikely, someone will do same typo mistake and hence it is not recommended. As for what you should do, in my POV, you can delete the post.

Comment: @Rajesh. Yes I agree and that's exactly what I did. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` is not a very helpfull console error... so I thought that this forum would be a good place for asking that question as I couldn't find on the web or doc other similar pb or similar question. I just don't understand why everyone put -1... other typo question were not so harshly welcome...